# Get value from dynamic link id

Tags: php, jquery

I am generating dynamic id's based on the results from MySQL and this is working ok. However, I need to get value of id and whatever i try, it either comes back undefined or blank. I would appreciate any help if someone could point out my error. Thanks

```
<?php
    while ($inboxrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($inboxresult)) {
     $id = $inboxrow["id_frm"];
     $message = $inboxrow["message_frm"];
     $date = $inboxrow["date_frm"];
     $date = strtotime( $date );
     $date = date( 'd/m/Y H:i:s', $date );
     $from = $inboxrow["from_frm"];
     $subject = $inboxrow["subject_frm"];

    echo '<div class="msgHdr" style="font-size: 13px; margin-right: 20px; margin-bottom: 10px; padding: 7px; border: 1px solid #ccc; height: auto; background: #fcfaf7">';
    echo '<span style="font-weight: bold;">' . $from . '</span>';
    echo '<br />';
    echo "<a class='dynid' href='#' id='" .$id. "'>" .$subject. "</a>" . '<span style="float: right; font-size: 12px;">' .$date. '</span>';
    echo '</div>';

?>
```

js

```
$(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '.msgHdr', function() {
    //console.log(id);
    var anc = $(".dynid").find("#id").text();
    console.log(anc);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your code you need

```
$(document).on('click', '.msgHdr', function() {
  var $link = $(this).find(".dynid"); 
  var subject = $link.text(); 
  var id = $link.attr("id");
});
```

Comment: Excellent. Thanks very much. I can accept answer in 6 mins

Answer (score 1):

You should probably do something like:

```
    $(function() {
        $( ".msgHdr" ).click(function() {
            var anc = $(this).find(".dynid").text();
            console.log(anc);
        });
    });
```